# JFileChooser java scrolling loses display pixels

Tags: java, swing, scroll, netbeans-7

In NetBeans IDE 7.4 my GUI looks fine. When I debug or run the JFileChooser from withing the IDE it looks fine (I'm using the Nimbus L&F).  When I build it and run it from the command-line (using the same Nimbus L&F that is programmed into the Main method) the JfileChooser dialog messes up the display when scrolled. It's still Nimbus, but the display pane loses all kinds of pixels.  The same pixel-drop happens in the version executed from the commandline regarless of the L&F I choose.

** LATER:

WRONG JVM:  There's another "java" executable in my environment that was being picked up.  The OpenJDK.  When I forced the "java" executable to run the Sun/Oracle jvm it worked just fine.

Comment: Provide a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and pictures...

Comment: Thanks - I found the solution was a buggy JVM (OpenJdk).  I did try to upload pics but didn't have enough brownie points to do so. It was disallowed.